# Offline downlevel migration succeeded-what is it, can it be suppressed, slows machine a bit for a minute

Tags: windows, event-log

Offline downlevel migration succeeded-what is it, can it be suppressed as it seems to give me the blue circle for a while when coming out of sleep or restarting, etc..

Am on Windows 11 22H2 22621.1992 on a Lenovo Legion 5i 16IRX8 laptop, Intel based.
When the cursor shows a blue circle and then it disappears after about a minute I will see thes3e entries in event viewer: Successfully scheduled Software Protection service for re-start at 2023-11-12T18:04:51Z. Reason: RulesEngine. Event ID: 16394
Followed by (more recent next entry) Successfully scheduled Software Protection service for re-start at 2023-11-12T18:04:51Z. Reason: RulesEngine. Event ID: 16384

This is a home computer. Not connected to a server or in a group.

Perhaps it is schedule in creating a restore point in the future as I did not find a new one created. Or perhaps it is going to test if Office or something is licensed.

Searched Google which had some results but no tangible answer.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.